# How do you selectively sync a database in Django?

Tags: mysql, django, oracle, python-2.7

Right now in Django, I have two databases:

1. A default MySQL database for my app and
2. an external Oracle database that, for my purposes, is read-only

There are far more tables in the external database than I need data from, and also I would like to modify the db layout slightly. Is there a way I can selectively choose what data in the external database I would like to sync to my database? The external database is dynamic, and I would like my app to reflect that.

Ex I would like to do something like this:

Say the external database has two tables (out of 100) as follows:

Table47

- Eggs
- Spam
- Sausage

Table48

- Name
- Age
- Color

And I want to keep the data like:

Foo

- Eggs
- Spam
- Type (a foreign key)

Bar

- Name
- Age
- Type (foreign key)

Type

- Some fields

Is there a way I could do this in Django?

Answer (score -1):

Basically write models that match what you want your destination tables to be and then write something to migrate data between the two. I'd make this a comment if I could but not enough rep.

Comment: Is there a way to do this that keeps the destination database up-to-date? If I understand correctly, a data migration only transfers the data once?

Comment: Create a database job that runs the "migrate" procedure periodically.

Comment: Yeah: I have a similar setup with a scheduled task that loads data from one database into a web app.